# CodeRAD2 - buttons overflowMenuStyle issue

Tags: codenameone

When using `overflowMenuStyle="PopupMenu"` the actions is clickable and everything works fine. However when I use `overflowMenuStyle="ActionSheet"` the actions is not responding to clicks/touch. So, am I missing something or is this a bug?

```
<buttons actionTemplate.uiid="MyMenuActions" actionCategory="MAIN_TOP_OVERFLOW_MENU" limit="1" overflowActionTemplate.uiid="MainSheetAction" overflowMenuStyle="ActionSheet" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in CodeRAD version 2.0.3.  Update your CodeRAD version in both your pom.xml and common/pom.xml files, and you should find that it starts working.